# Android ListFragment multiple checkbox in a single row

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I'm facing some problems, so I though maybe someone could help me as I'm at dead end and have no idea how to fix this. So I'm creating an app, which use List Fragment with multiple (exactly 5) checkbox'es and 1 text view in a single row. So the first problem is: I want to check only one of 5 checkbox'es(that means if I check first one, then other(second,third,fourth,fifth box) shouldn't be checked and so on...). And the second and most important problem is that there will be like 10-20 rows, so as I scroll down/up some rows gets recycled and checked boxes become unchecked or randomly checked, so how I'm supposed to store data, so that checkbox'es which were checked won't be unchecked or randomly checked after scrolling up or down.
Also onListItemClick do not work too :(

***ListFragment:***

```
package com.android4dev.navigationview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.*;


public class SymptomsSelectionFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_symptoms_selection, container, false);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2","shitPhone","testPhone", "boomPhone", "meskaPhone" };
        ArrayAdapter<Question> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                getQuestion());
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.hide();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO implement some logic
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Snackbar.make(getListView(), item+" selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),position+" <--- Nr.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private List<Question> getQuestion() {
        List<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();
        list.add(get("Linux"));
        list.add(get("Windows7"));
        list.add(get("Suse"));
        list.add(get("Eclipse"));
        list.add(get("Ubuntu"));
        list.add(get("Solaris"));
        list.add(get("Android"));
        list.add(get("iPhone"));
        // Initially select one of the items
        //list.get(1).setSelected(true);
        return list;
    }

    private Question get(String s) {
        return new Question(s);
    }







}
```

***ArrayAdapter:***

```
import java.util.List;
package com.android4dev.navigationview;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.Image;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {

    private final List<Question> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Question> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout_symptoms_selection, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox1;
        protected CheckBox checkbox2;
        protected CheckBox checkbox3;
        protected CheckBox checkbox4;
        protected CheckBox checkbox5;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_symptoms_selection, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label_symptom);
            viewHolder.checkbox1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            viewHolder.checkbox2 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            viewHolder.checkbox3 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            viewHolder.checkbox4 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
            viewHolder.checkbox5 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.button5);
            viewHolder.checkbox1
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                     boolean isChecked) {
                            Question element = (Question) viewHolder.checkbox1
                                    .getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            viewHolder.checkbox2
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                     boolean isChecked) {
                            Question element2 = (Question) viewHolder.checkbox2
                                    .getTag();
                            element2.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            viewHolder.checkbox3
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                     boolean isChecked) {
                            Question element3 = (Question) viewHolder.checkbox3
                                    .getTag();
                            element3.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            viewHolder.checkbox4
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                     boolean isChecked) {
                            Question element4 = (Question) viewHolder.checkbox4
                                    .getTag();
                            element4.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            viewHolder.checkbox5
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                     boolean isChecked) {
                            Question element5 = (Question) viewHolder.checkbox5
                                    .getTag();
                            element5.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox1.setTag(list.get(position));
            viewHolder.checkbox2.setTag(list.get(position));
            viewHolder.checkbox3.setTag(list.get(position));
            viewHolder.checkbox4.setTag(list.get(position));
            viewHolder.checkbox5.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox1.setTag(list.get(position));
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox2.setTag(list.get(position));
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox3.setTag(list.get(position));
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox4.setTag(list.get(position));
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox5.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox1.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.checkbox2.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.checkbox3.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.checkbox4.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.checkbox5.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
}
```

***QuestionClass:***

```
 package com.android4dev.navigationview;

/**
 * Created by Home-PC on 10/19/2016.
 */

public class Question {
    private String name;
    private boolean selected;

    public Question(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        selected = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

***fragment_symptoms_selection.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    >


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="No data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***row_layout_symptoms_selection.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
    tools:context=".SymptomsActivity"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_symptom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/text"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_drawable"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/CheckBox1"
            />
        <CheckBox
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_drawable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/CheckBox2"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_drawable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/CheckBox3"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_drawable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/CheckBox4"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_drawable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/CheckBox5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you give example of how should I do it? As I'm newbie and just learning android. I would be very grateful :)

Comment: you can also save your states inside shared preferences. if you want to handle so that the user can choose only one option you can do that with if statements.

Comment: So first off, onCheckChangeListener has the "isChecked" variable. How come you're calling isChecked() on the View? IsChecked is notoriously incorrect in many situations. I don't think that you'd get the correct information from the button view. Use the isChecked boolean instead.

Comment: You have some examples below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, If you need only one option selected at time, consider using [RadioButton](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) implementation.
Second, Are you storing your data in a sql database? If you are already using a sql database, this is the way to store the checkboxes state:

a- In `Question Class`, add this:

```
int status   
public int getStatus() {
        return status;
   }
public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
```

b- In your database adapter, add STATUS to your table items.

c- In your getView method handle checked items like this:

```
holder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        Item changeItem = (Item) cb.getTag();
                        changeItem.setStatus(cb.isChecked() ? 1 : 0);
                        mDbHelper.updateItem(changeItem);
                             }
                     });
```

See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) to learn how store data in sql database.
If you are not using database, maybe you need to use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is ONE way how can you let the user choose only one option. better way would be to implement the onCheckChangeListener and do the same thing so you dont have to make the same method all over again :) to store the values that the user chooses you should use the "extends Application" approach.

```
    final CheckBox cbOne = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbOne);
    final CheckBox cbTwo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbTwo);
    final CheckBox cbThree = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbThree);

    cbOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                cbTwo.setClickable(false);
                cbThree.setClickable(false);

                cbTwo.setChecked(false);
                cbThree.setChecked(false);


            } else {

                cbTwo.setClickable(true);
                cbThree.setClickable(true);

            }

        }
    });

    cbTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


            if (isChecked) {

                cbOne.setClickable(false);
                cbThree.setClickable(false);

                cbOne.setChecked(false);
                cbThree.setChecked(false);


            } else {

                cbOne.setClickable(true);
                cbThree.setClickable(true);


            }


        }
    });


    cbThree.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


            if (isChecked) {

                cbTwo.setClickable(false);
                cbOne.setClickable(false);

                cbTwo.setChecked(false);
                cbOne.setChecked(false);


            } else {

                cbTwo.setClickable(true);
                cbOne.setClickable(true);


            }


        }
    });
```